# Oracle sql query to create new table in S1 schema by copying from S2 Schema

Tags: oracle10g

Oracle sql query to create new table in S1 schema by copying from S2 Schema
CREATE TABLE HR.EMP_DEPT LIKE TARGET.EMPLOYEES_DEPT
INSERT INTO HR.EMP_DEPT SELECT * FROM TARGET.EMPLOYEES_DEPT

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want

```
CREATE TABLE s1.table_name
AS
SELECT *
  FROM s2.table_name
```

That will create an `s1.table_name` table with the same columns and data types as the `s2.table_name` table.  It will not, however, create the same set of indexes, constraints, or triggers that exist on the `s2.table_name` table.  You could use the `dbms_metadata` package to extract the DDL for those objects and modify the DDL to create those dependent objects on the `s1` table.  Or you could use the export and import utilities (classic or DataPump) to export the table from `s2` and import it into the `s1` schema.